# mod_rewrite subdomain + dir

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, dir

I'm ashamed for having to ask this becous there is soooo many questions and answers out there about this but I have search and tried for weeks without positive results.

I have file upload page with the url:
files.example.com

When a user is uploading a file its placed in a subdir:
files.example.com/files/file.jpg
So when a user is going to view the file, he has to visit that url.

But I want to remove the dir files/
So the user can view the file with this url:
files.example.com/file.jpg

I have placed a .htaccess file in:
files.example.com/.htaccess

And tried everything i can find. Ex.:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^files/?(.*)$ /$1
```

mod_rewrite subdomain + dir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule is the wring way round. Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]*\.jpg)$ files/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I get an internal server error (500) with that code. And if I remove the "jpg" ^(.*)$ /files/$1 [L] I get 404

Comment: @Patrik: On testing I found this caused a recursive rewrite (hence the 500 error). I've updated the regexp slightly to prevent this. Please try the new version above.

Comment: Awesome! So whats the difference between [^/]* and (.*)? Not matching / ? But I still have a little problem, I want users to be able to upload any file. So if i remove jpg I will be "directed" to the files dir if i try to access index.php. So can I say "only redirect if filetype is not .php"?

Comment: `[^/]` means match any character except slash. `.` means match any character. I would suggest only redirecting the extensions you want to redirect. If you have multiple image types, you could use something like `^([^/]*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png))$`